# ec2にrails4 + Unicorn + Nginxをインストール

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ec2 + rails4 + Unicorn + Nginx 環境を構築しているのですが、

```
bundle exec unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D
```

でunicornを起動するとエラーがでます。

```
log/unicorn.log
```

には

```
 bundler: failed to load command: unicorn_rails (/usr/share/nginx/html/moin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn_rails)
 Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'.
 Gem Load Error is: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. 
 See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
```

とでています。

```
vi Gemfile
```

の設定を以下に変更して`bundle install`しましたがエラーが直りません。

```
 # gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
 gem 'uglifier'
```

どこの設定を変更したらよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エラーメッセージの通り `JavaScript runtime` がインストールされていないようです。
`nodejs` をインストールしてみてはいかがでしょうか？